# Get inserted id from mysql insert procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I create a procedure for insert statement with some input parameters. But i want to get the inserted id or inserted row from the same procedure.I created using oracle, that is working fine. But i don't know in mysql. And spend more time to get this.i can't.

Answer (score 1):

**MySQL** solution:

After running the `insert` statement, execute

```
select last_insert_id() into lastId;
```

Change your SP to include an `OUT` parameter as

```
OUT lastId bigint
```

or simply run

```
select last_insert_id();
```

to return a result set by the SP;

**Refer to**:

- [**MySQL: LAST_INSERT_ID()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

  - Value of the AUTOINCREMENT column for the last INSERT